# Why there is a difference in "import" vs. "import *"?

Tags: python, import

```
"""module a.py"""
test = "I am test"
_test = "I am _test"
__test = "I am __test"
```

=============

```
~ $ python
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, Apr 16 2009, 09:17:39) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 5250)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from a import *
>>> test
'I am test'
>>> _test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '_test' is not defined
>>> __test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__test' is not defined
>>> import a
>>> a.test
'I am test'
>>> a._test
'I am _test'
>>> a.__test
'I am __test'
>>>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Variables with a leading "_" (underbar) are not *public names* and will not be imported when `from x import *` is used.

Here, `_test` and `__test` are not *public* names.

From the [import](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) statement description:

> If the list of identifiers is replaced
>   by a star ('*'), all public names
>   defined in the module are bound in the
>   local namespace of the import
>   statement..
>
> The public names defined by a module
>   are determined by checking the
>   module’s namespace for a variable
>   named __all__; if defined, it must be
>   a sequence of strings which are names
>   defined or imported by that module.
>   The names given in __all__ are all
>   considered public and are required to
>   exist. **If __all__ is not defined, the
>   set of public names includes all names
>   found in the module’s namespace which
>   do not begin with an underscore
>   character ('_').** __all__ should
>   contain the entire public API. It is
>   intended to avoid accidentally
>   exporting items that are not part of
>   the API (such as library modules which
>   were imported and used within the
>   module).